# Discover does not start on Kubuntu 23.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, discover-software-center

For some reason `Discover` doesn't start on Kubuntu for me. This has started happening starting a few weeks ago. I can run `apt-get` commands just fine from the console with no warnings or errors. There is no output on the console if I run the command `plasma-discover --mode update` in Konsole.

Also if I launch `plasma-discover --mode update` under another account, say root using `sudo`, it starts up properly.

How can I debug this further? I suspect some config file is corrupted but I cannot figure out which one.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ubuntu Ask community.** To make it easier to diagnose your issue, please edit your question to include any errors that are generated when you run this application (doing so from command line should provide some feedback, warnings, or errors). Thanks

Comment: So, no error when running `plasma-discover`?

Comment: Correct, I am stumped.